# ValueTuple With WPF Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tuples, valuetuple

why binding to `ValueTuple` property members (like Item1, Item2 ect) dont work?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtTest" Text="{Binding Item1}" />
```

the code:

```
txtTest.DataContext = ("Item A", "Another Item..");
```

output window:

> BindingExpression path error: 'Item1' property not found on 'object' ''ValueTuple`2'

However in `Tuple` It always worked.

Comment: `this.DataContext = new Tuple<string, string>("item 1", "item 2");` this is working fine.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Right. I already mentioned this in my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetuple(v=vs.110).aspx), `Item1` and `Item2` of a `ValueTuple` are fields rather than properties and you can only bind to public properties in WPF.

So if you want to be able to bind to a tuple, you should use the `Tuple` class.